# Lavalamp for jQuery: Can't get first level menu clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, lavalamp

I am using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIAEE.jpg) version of the lavalamp jquery plugin and I would like the travel link to have a submenu with options like (**TRAVEL - >DOMESTIC | INTERNATIONAL | SPACE | DARK AGES | GOLDEN ERA**) and also to be able to navigate to the top-level **travel.html** page.

Travel should link to travel.html and **DOMESTIC, INTERNATIONAL, SPACE, DARK AGES, GOLDEN ERA** should all be linking to their respective pages.

[image]

I felt as though it shouldn't be this difficult but somehow I am not able to get it done.

Many thanks.

**EDIT: ADDING CODE**

**HTML**

```
<ul class="lavaLampWithImage" id="1">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html" >Travel</a>
        <div>
            <ul>                    
                <li><a  href="domestic.html">Domestic</a></li>
                <li><a  href="international.html">International</a></li>
                <li><a  href="space.html">Space</a></li>
                <li><a  href="dark-ages.html">Dark Ages</a></li>
                <li><a  href="golden-era.html">Golden Era</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ride an elephant</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#1").lavaLamp({
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function($) {
$.fn.lavaLamp = function(o) {
    o = $.extend({ fx: "linear", speed: 500, click: function(){} }, o || {});

    return this.each(function() {
        var me = $(this), noop = function(){},
            $back = $('<li class="back"><div class="left"></div></li>').appendTo(me),
            $li = $("li", this), curr = $("li.current", this)[0] || $($li[0]).addClass("current")[0];

        $li.not(".back").hover(function() {
            move(this);
        }, noop);

        $(this).hover(noop, function() {
            move(curr);
        });

        $li.click(function(e) {
            setCurr(this);
            return o.click.apply(this, [e, this]);
        });

        setCurr(curr);

        function setCurr(el) {
            $back.css({ "left": el.offsetLeft+"px", "width": el.offsetWidth+"px" });
            curr = el;
        };

        function move(el) {
            $back.each(function() {
                $.dequeue(this, "fx"); }
            ).animate({
                width: el.offsetWidth,
                left: el.offsetLeft
            }, o.speed, o.fx);
        };

    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
.lavaLampWithImage {
    position: relative;
    height: 29px;
    width: 421px;
    background: url("bg.gif") no-repeat top;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li.back {
    background: url("lava.gif") no-repeat right -30px;
    width: 9px; height: 30px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
}

.lavaLampWithImage li.back .left {
    background: url("lava.gif") no-repeat top left;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 9px; /* 7px is the width of the rounded shape */
}

.lavaLampWithImage li a {
    font: bold 14px arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    top: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto 10px;    
}

.lavaLampWithImage li a:hover, .lavaLampWithImage li a:active, .lavaLampWithImage li a:visited {
    border: none;
}
```

What I basically were trying to achieve was to have the **Travel** first level menu-tab linked to `travel.html` and to be able to have the lavalamp effect even on `travel.html`.

Comment: You should post the code you've created and when possible, a jsFiddle.

Comment: @j08691: I have added the relevant code. Please take a look. Will keep jsfiddle in mind for future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A typical HTML widget consists of 3 distinct components when implementing a plug-in, including CSS, HTML layout, and the jQuery plug-in script w/ properties wanted.

Start with the **HTML layout**:

```
<ul class="lavaLamp">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Plant a tree</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Travel</a>
            <ul>    <!-- submenus of travel parent menu -->
                <li><a href="#">Domestic</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">International</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Space</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ride an elephant</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Note*** that the lavalamp plug-in automatically add's a background list item tag that moves the background on hover event

Now let's do some basic styling with **CSS:**:

```
.lavaLamp {
    position: relative;
    height: 29px; width: 421px;
    background: url("../image/bg.gif") no-repeat top;
    padding: 15px; margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* Force the list to flow horizontally */
.lavaLamp li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
/* Represents the background of the highlighted menu-item. */
.lavaLamp li.back {
    background: url("../image/lava.gif") no-repeat right -30px;
    width: 9px; height: 30px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
 }

 .lavaLamp li.back .left {
    background: url("../image/lava.gif") no-repeat top left;
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 9px;
        }
  /* Styles for each menu-item. */
  .lavaLamp li a {
    position: relative; overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 14px arial;
    color: #fff; outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px; top: 7px;
    z-index: 10; letter-spacing: 0;
    float: left; display: block;
    margin: auto 10px;
    }
```

The above CSS should be edited to your liking for styling purposes. Other CSS selections can be added by jQuery $('SELECTOR').addClass('className');

Now for the **plug-in**. Most of the javascript work is taken care by the Lava Lamp plugin itself, so all you have to do is add the .js files to your project, reference them in the web form you're using them in, or a master page, and add script tags to place the fired events in:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script>
<!-- Optional -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.easing.js"></script>

<!-- Place this section in your webform using the lava lamp menu-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { $(".lavaLamp").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 700 })});
</script>
```

Checkout the [lava lamp site](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/lavalamp2) for the latest code updates, such as object properties for different settings.

**Edit1:** To fix the sub-menu bugs, visit [this](http://hekimian-williams.com/?p=146) site to change code in the plug-in file.

Any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Hi HotKey, thanks for the detailed reply. What I actually wanted was to make `<a href="#">Travel</a>` to be linking `travel.html`. So `<a href="travel.html">Travel</a>` and then have the lavalamp working the way it is supposed on `travel.html`. What happens is that I lost the lavalamp effect when its on `travel.html` page.  So What I actually wanted was to have the first level menu to be linkable but still retain the lavalamp effect. I havent come across any post on the web that actually explains that as first level menu are considered not linked to any page for themselves.

Comment: And being a non-javascript guy I just couldnt get it solved even after spending hours on it :(

Comment: I've added some code in case it helps solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Since LavaLamp is no longer restricted to ul and ol elements since version 1.3.4., there are new enhanced and target options that can be used to play nice with sub-level menus, without having to dig through the JS. You can also add the 'noLava' class to sub-elements that you don't want lava-lamp to hover on. 

It looks like in your example, you want to be able to target ALL menus AND sub-menus because you have anchor tags set. I would think that naming the sub menu ul class the same as the parent ul might fix this, or setting the container and targets correctly.

Comment: Sorry I do not have time today to look into your code, BUT I did come across a really cool lava lamp example that is pure CSS3. Here it is: http://css.dzone.com/articles/pure-css3-lavalamp-menu